# Use powershell to add users to a group

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have two zones for the web application. One is the default zone which uses windows authentication and one is the Intranet zone which uses a claims based provider for authentication.

I want to use powershell to add users to a group. Now in the default zone I can do it easily since it can resolve it correctly but not when I am trying to add users which are in the intranet authentication provider which is Azure AD.

I am using this powershell

```
$Users = "test@testcorp.onmicrosoft.com"
$siteCollUrl = "https://test/sites/test"
$group = "powershellcreated"
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity $siteCollUrl
    $web.EnsureUser($User)  
    Set-SPUser -Identity $User -Web $siteCollUrl -Group $group
```

I am getting an error that it cannot resolve the user because it is looking into the default zone.

Can someone please tell me how I can have powershell to add users to two different zones which have different authentication providers.

"https://test/sites/test" is intranet with azure ad authentication
"http://test/sites/test" is default with windows authentication
Thanks

Comment: Have you defined the claims provider for $User ?

Comment: Nope..How do you do that...I can go to the https intranet zone and add the user through people picker but not through powershell script.

Answer (score 0):

This article'll explain why it doesn't work when you try to add an Azude AD User :

https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/what-you-need-to-know-about-using-ensureuser-in-claims-based-web-apps-in-sharepoint-2010-and-sharepoint-2013/

You just need to specify the claims as I said and it should work fine.

Taken from the article :

```
$claim = New-SPClaimsPrincipal -Identity "domain\login" -IdentityType WindowsSamAccountName
$web.EnsureUser($claim.ToEncodedString());
```